# How deletion works in PythonToolKit?

Tags: python, rally

I just started using Rally API and fairly new in python as well, I am trying to delete an entry from Rally, please refer to the following code:

```
from rallyCRUD import *

rally.delete('Changeset')

project = rally.getProject()
thisId = "1925546409"
rally.delete('Changeset', thisId)
```

This code gives the following error: "delete takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)", I understand I am missing one argument, but not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciate!

Thanks,

Cheng

Answer (score 0):

From the pyral code on github the following documentation:

Given a Rally entityName, an identification of a specific Rally instance of that entity (in either OID or FormattedID format), issue the REST DELETE call and return an indication of whether the delete operation was successful.

The method signature is:

```
def delete(self, entityName, itemIdent, workspace='current', project='current', **kwargs)
```

Source: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/blob/master/pyral/restapi.py